# Angular component outputs/events with a deep component hierarchy

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on a complex Angular2 application and I'm trying to follow the pattern of having pure, reusuable, "dumb" components wrapped by a larger "smart" component that handles API interaction (or synching with my reactive store, or whatever else dealing with external dependencies).

One of my child components `<yet-another-presentational-component>`(see code below) emits an event that needs to be synced with the API. However, it's 3 levels deep inside other different components. That creates a problem, because, now every component that contains `<yet-another-presentational-component>` has to handle its events in order for them to be passed up the chain to the smart parent component. This seems awfully un-DRY; if something changes about how `<yet-another-presentational-component>` emits, then I have to update several components.

On the other hand, if I were to inject my `ApiService` into `<yet-another-presentational-component>` (thus making it a "smart" component), that would solve my event "bucket brigade" issue, but creates another problem: now `<yet-another-presentational-component>` is not as reusable. Plus, it violates the contract of presentational/smart components (as I understand it, at least).

With Angular1, at least `$scope.$emit` (or requiring parents) could be used to solve this problem. **How could I redesign this widget to avoid an event "bucket brigade", while also adhering to good patterns of "smart" vs "dumb" components.**

```
<!-- Sample app markup architecture -->

<smart-component-with-api-access>

   <dumb-presentational-component-1 (changeStatus)="handleStatusChange($event)">

       <dumb-presentational-component-details (changeStatus)="handleStatusChange($event)">

           <yet-another-presentational-component (changeStatus)="handleStatusChange($event)">

           </yet-another-presentational-component>

       <dumb-presentational-component-details>
   </dumb-presentational-component-1>
</smart-component-with-api-access>
```

Comment: You can use bubbling DOM events or a generic event bus (custom service) like `$scope.emit` or just go with the shared service you mentioned yourself.

Comment: Would [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html) not suit your purpose?

Answer (score 7):

This guide on component interaction is useful:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Rather than simple output events, you should use a service. The `yet-another-presentational-component` can then emit a change to the service, whilst the 
`smart-component-with-api-access` can subscribe to the service and act accordingly.

Example:

A simple notification service "notification.service.ts":

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  constructor() { }

  private notificationSource = new Subject<string>();

  public notificationReceived = this.notificationSource.asObservable();

  notify(newMessage: string) {
    this.notificationSource.next(newMessage);
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

Then in the **smart-component-with-api-access** import the service, add to the constructor and subscribe to notifications:

```
import { NotificationService } from './shared/services/notification.service';
...
export class SmartComponentWithAPIAccess {

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {

    this.notificationService.notificationReceived.subscribe(
      message => {
        // do something with message such as access API
      }
    );  
  }
}
```

In the **yet-another-presentational-component** import the notification service and declare in the constructor like the above, then when you want to fire the notification / event:

```
this.notificationService.notify("I have a message");
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful...can't believe I didn't think about using a service. However, say that this component tree is used 3 times on a single screen. Using a service as an event bus here hurts the reusabiltiy...I wouldn't want all 3 instances `SmartComponentWithApiAccess` to receive the event emitted in just a single instance. Could I register it as a provider at the component level to prevent this?

Comment: You can register the service at any level, and yes you could provide it at the component level. 
Providing it there would give you one instance of the service, and the `SmartComponentWithApiAccess` can still subscribe.

one thing to watch out with.. if one of the component trees is removed from the screen, the `SmartComponentWithApiAccess` would need to make sure it unsubscribes from the service using the `ngOnDestroy` function.

Comment: My example is taken from an app i wrote where the service is in the main app.component. This allows any components in my app to send notifications, where the app component is subscribed. It can display all messages in a message box, allowing once snippet of code to display the message. And its consistent!