# Is it possible to call ConfirmationService from another service/component?

Tags: angular, primeng

I would like to declare an application wide  (i.e: inside app.component.html) and then being able to display it by calling ConfirmationService.confirm() from any component or any service.

Is that scenario possible?

I tried to add it to app.component.html
CODE:

```
<p-confirmDialog key="mainDialog" class="styleDialog" [baseZIndex]="10000"></p-confirmDialog>
```

Then to call it from a service
CODE: SELECT ALL

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FooService{
  constructor(
    private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
  ) {}
  doSomeStuff() {
    ...
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      key:'mainDialog',
      message: 'some message',
      header: 'Warning',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      acceptLabel: 'ok',
      rejectVisible: false,
      accept: () => {},
    });
  }
}
```

But this does not do anything.

Am i missing something? Is this a supported scenario? Or do I need to implement my own 'dialog as a service' mechanism?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to do this with a service. Have a look at this question, which has an answer which you may find useful..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855597/angular-component-outputs-events-with-a-deep-component-hierarchy/41857043#41857043

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular component outputs/events with a deep component hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855597/angular-component-outputs-events-with-a-deep-component-hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

On a previous Angular 13 project using NgModules I could inject PrimeNg ConfirmationService in any component and it would display the  component from my app.component.html.
Starting a new project with Angular 17  this time heavily using standalone components and this doesn't work anymore. I guess that PrimeNg services aren't singleton in that case and a new instance is returned for each component it is injected to.

To work around this I built a wrapper around PrimeNg  and the ConfirmationService.

1° confirm-dialog-wrapper.service.ts
The `providedIn: 'root'` ensure I'm working with a singleton this time. See https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConfirmDialogWrapperService {
  private _confirmationSubject: Subject<Confirmation> = new Subject();
  public readonly confirmationSubject: Observable<Confirmation> = this._confirmationSubject.asObservable();

  public confirm(confirmation: Confirmation): void {
    this._confirmationSubject.next(confirmation)
  }
}
```

2° confirm-dialog-wrapper.component.html

```
<p-confirmDialog>
  <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
    <p-button label="Confirm" (click)="confirm()"></p-button>
    <p-button label="Cancel" (click)="reject()"></p-button>
  </ng-template>
</p-confirmDialog>
```

3° confirm-dialog-wrapper.component.ts
Note the `?.()` syntax since accept and reject can be undefined.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'confirm-dialog-wrapper',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ConfirmDialogModule],
  providers: [ConfirmationService],
  templateUrl: './confirm-dialog-wrapper.component.html'
})
export class ConfirmDialogWrapperComponent {
  confirmation: Confirmation | undefined;

  constructor(
    public confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
    private confirmationService: ConfirmDialogWrapperService) {
    confirmationService.confirmationSubject
      .subscribe((confirmation: Confirmation): void => {
        this.confirmation = confirmation
        confirmationService.confirm(confirmation)
      })
  }

  confirm() {
    this.confirmation?.accept?.()
    this.confirmationService.close()
  }

  reject() {
    this.confirmation?.reject?.()
    this.confirmationService.close()
  }
}
```

4° app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<confirm-dialog-wrapper></confirm-dialog-wrapper>
```

5° Now I just have to call the confirm() method of the ConfirmDialogWrapperService which accepts a regular PrimeNg Confirmation object. Example below

```
 this.confirmDialogWrapperService.confirm({
      message: "Please confirm you wish to delete this stuff",
      accept: () => {this.delete(this.stuff)}
    })
```